# What is meant when someone says OP?

Tags: support

I constantly see people reference OP or "the OP"... what is OP?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

OP is an acronym for [Original Poster.](http://www.google.com.au/search?sourceid=chrome&ie=UTF-8&q=op+original+poster)

Answer (score 4):

In threaded conversations it can also mean "original post." But since that sort of "conversation" doesn't happen here, the other meaning of "original poster" is what we're referring to.